# Odd symbol below my stamina bar

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was playing Dark Souls 2 recently and noticed an odd symbol below my stamina bar (where my ring status effects usually are). It appeared to be a white shield in a red square.

I have played the game before and have never come across this symbol for 4 different characters.

I unequipped all my gear and it was still there. I had not used any consumables either.

I did a bit of looking around and found a similar thing which turned out to be a feature that set up an auto walk after pressing a designated key.

Note: I use a controller, the only time I use the keyboard is when I'm typing in my characters name.

Are there more than 1, and if so, what do they all mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature for Auto-Block, meaning, your character will always be blocking. The default key to enable or disable is "M".

Comment: Having never played on PC, 'autoblock' sounds horrendous.

Comment: I have edited the question to cover more of these icons and their meaning

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if these have symbols since i only used a controller this far (will check when i have the time if there are any) but there are 2 more things that are toggleable when using a PC though, **one of them is Walking / running ( Z ), the other is running, sprinting ( X ).**